# Eclipse define build variable in pre-build

Tags: linux, shell, gcc, build, eclipse-cdt

I created simple shell script file in /tmp/test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'aaaa'
```

In Eclipse->C/C++ Build->Setting->Build Step -> Pre-build steps->Command , I added `TEST =/tmp/test.sh`

Than in C/C++ Build->Setting->Tool Settings->Cross GCC Compiler ->Command line pattern ,  I tried to used this variable like `-D ${TEST}` so it pass `-D aaaa` (the output of shell script)

But in build console I didn't see that `-D aaaa` have been passed to gcc , In fact I didn't see `-D` at all

why is that? I want to set variable in pre-build that will be the output of shell script and use it with gcc command line pattern

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the CDT managed build does not allow running external commands for assigning environment variables, build variables or command line flags, thus executing the script at that stage doesn't work.

Not a direct answer to the question on how to do that with the gcc command line pattern, but if you really only want to pass defines to the preprocessor with results you got from the script, you may use the script instead to update or create a header file that is included somewhere, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "#ifndef __MYVARHEADER__" > ../include/myvarheader.h
echo "#define __MYVARHEADER__" >> ../include/myvarheader.h
echo "#define aaaa" >> ../include/myvarheader.h
echo "#endif" >> ../include/myvarheader.h
```

In Eclipse->C/C++ Build->Setting->Build Step -> Pre-build steps->Command, just execute `/tmp/test.sh`

Comment: The CDT does allow running external commands for assigning environment variables, build variables or command line flags

Answer (score 1):

This type of thing is done via `makefile.defs`.

```
$(info BEGIN makefile.defs)
# Note that git describe uses glob(7) patterns
GIT_REV     := $(shell git describe --dirty --match 'V[[:digit:]]*.[[:digit:]]*.[[:digit:]]')
GIT_BRANCH  := $(shell git branch --show-current)
GIT_HASH    := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)

GIT_FLAGS += -DGIT_REV="$(GIT_REV)" 
GIT_FLAGS += -DGIT_BRANCH="$(GIT_BRANCH)" 
GIT_FLAGS += -DGIT_HASH="$(GIT_HASH)" 

$(info GIT_REV: $(GIT_REV))
$(info GIT_BRANCH: $(GIT_BRANCH))
$(info GIT_HASH: $(GIT_HASH))
$(info END makefile.defs)
```

You now have `GIT_FLAGS` defined in your make environment.  Once you do that your C code will have GIT_REV, GIT_BRANCH, and GIT_HASH defined.

You place `makefile.defs` at the top-level of your C project.

To pass that into your compiler add $(GIT_FLAGS) to your Miscellaneous flags ...

[image]

If you were to look in /Debug you will see a makefile.  In that makefile you will see a line like, `-include ../makefile.defs`.  That is how your makefile.defs gets used.

You could also provide `makefile.init` and `makefile.targets` to further customize your build process.